# Why doesn't this map command using anova_test work?

Tags: r, tidyverse, anova

Here is a picture of my df:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBy5.png)

This is the code I used to make it:

```
social_reward_AOV_data <- data %>%
  mutate(reward = recode(reward, "0" = "loss", "1" = "gain")) %>%
  mutate(social_reward = paste(partner_name, reward, sep = "_")) %>%
  convert_as_factor(reward, social_reward, partner_name) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(arousal, valence, rew_pred, mood_pred, amt_trusted), names_to =     "DV_names", values_to = "DV_values") %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(bonus, amt_returned, sequence, trial_num, contains("uncertainty"),     contains("congr"), mood, mood_vol, rew_vol, partner_name, reward)) %>%
  group_by(PID, social_reward, DV_names) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), mean)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(DV_names) %>%
  nest() %>%
  ungroup()
```

I want to run within-subject anovas on all my dependent variables (variables in DV_names - values in DV_values). Why doesn't this work?

```
    social_reward_AOV_data %>%
  mutate(
     aov_within = map(data, ~{anova_test(data = .x, dv = .x$DV_values, wid = .x$PID, within =     .x$social_reward) %>% tidy()})) %>%
    unnest(cols = aov_within)
```

I was expected multiple ANOVAS to be run on my DVs

```
data <- tibble::tibble(
  DV_names = c("amt_trusted", "arousal", "mood_pred", "rew_pred", "valence"),
  data = list(
    tibble::tibble(
      PID = rep(c(1, 4), each = 4L),
      social_reward = factor(rep(c("Circle_gain", "Circle_loss", "Evan_gain", "Evan_loss"), 2)),
      DV_values = c(
        0.48, 0.336666666666667, 0.433333333333333, 0.393333333333333, 0.55, 0.525,
        0.555, 0.566666666666667
      ),
    ),
    tibble::tibble(
      PID = rep(c(1, 4), each = 4L),
      social_reward = factor(rep(c("Circle_gain", "Circle_loss", "Evan_gain", "Evan_loss"), 2)),
      DV_values = c(
        36.8354166666667, 37.7854166666667, 22.01875, 23.3354166666667,
        141.698902885167, 28.7300074194667, 115.166682936667, -153.123317472667
      ),
    ),
    tibble::tibble(
      PID = rep(c(1, 4), each = 4L),
      social_reward = factor(rep(c("Circle_gain", "Circle_loss", "Evan_gain", "Evan_loss"), 2)),
      DV_values = c(
        46.9833333333333, 65.5, 36.8833333333333, 48.45, 56.8166666666667,
        52.1833333333333, 38.6666666666667, 38.7833333333333
      ),
    ),
    tibble::tibble(
      PID = rep(c(1, 4), each = 4L),
      social_reward = factor(rep(c("Circle_gain", "Circle_loss", "Evan_gain", "Evan_loss"), 2)),
      DV_values = c(
        46.6833333333333, 31.1333333333333, 41.1833333333333, 40.5166666666667,
        91.2166666666667, 88.55, 59.2666666666667, 58.6833333333333
      ),
    ),
    tibble::tibble(
      PID = rep(c(1, 4), each = 4L),
      social_reward = factor(rep(c("Circle_gain", "Circle_loss", "Evan_gain", "Evan_loss"), 2)),
      DV_values = c(
        39.55, -47.6333333333333, 1.86666666666667, -53.5, 172.233333333333,
        -148.833333333333, 161.3777974345, -163.099980683167
      ),
    )
  ),
)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example using `dput`

Comment: I added it w dput!